# "[Warning] this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90" need solution of this problem

Tags: c, literals, signed, integer-overflow

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
    long long a=2147488648, b;
    scanf("%lld", &a);
    b=a*2;
    scanf("%lld", &b);
    printf("%lld", &b);
}
```

I did instead "long long" - "int" and instead "%lld" - "%d" but this problem don't disappear

Comment: Please do not confuse C with C#, those are extremely different languages

Comment: `printf("%lld", b);`

Comment: @Cid Although it has nothig to do with the compiler warning.

Comment: And `long long a=2147488648LL`

Comment: @Shawn Yes, that will solve the problem, but why does the warning occur, is it important, and what changed between C90 and the next version?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Well, C89/C90 doesn't have a `long long` type... that was added in C99. Though of course it was a common compiler extension before then.

Comment: OP: What compiler and options to it are you using?

Comment: regarding: `printf("%lld", &b);`  This is taking the address of `b` (which should be printed using: `printf("%p", (void*)&b);`) and trying to print that address using a long long int `%lld` output format conversion specifier.  This causes the compiler to output the warning: *untitled1.c:12:16: warning: format ‘%lld’ expects argument of type ‘long long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int *’ [-Wformat=]*

Answer (score 1):

The underlying issue is that 2,147,488,648 is 2^31 +5000. The bit pattern, using 32 bits, is `1000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0011 1000 1000` (among others, the 32th bit is set). In a 32 bit two's complement integer representation this is, perhaps surprisingly, a large negative number, -2,147,478,648.<sup>1</sup>

This is clearly not the intent of the programmer. Therefore the standards mandate that a literal exceeding the value range of an int will have the type `long int` or `long long int`, whichever fits first, even though the literal has no `l` or `ll` suffix! <sup>2</sup> If the number is too large for both, the behavior is undefined, although implementations are free to provide and use larger integer types. In particular, with modern standards, the type of a decimal literal is never unsigned unless suffixed with `u`.

While I don't own a C90 standard copy, and the old drafts appear unavailable, [cppreference states](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) that indeed the rules changed in C99, and this is likely what the compiler warns about. Notably, C99 introduced a larger integer type, `long long int`, and mandated that it can at least represent the number 9223372036854775807. The rules for literal types in C90 were apparently that a literal like 2147488648  whose value is outside the signed `long int` range but inside the `unsigned long int` range be `unsigned long int`, in order to follow the programmer's intent to the degree possible. The reason that this rule has been abandoned is that unsigned values can have unintended consequences in expressions involving signed integers: All values are converted to unsigned first. That's OK for `2147488648u + 1` but it is not for `if(2147488648u  > -1)` (-1 is converted to the unsigned int 4294967295). Compilers typically warn about mixed sign expressions (gcc needs -Wextra though!). Demonstration:

```
$ cat unsigned-mismatch.c && gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o unsigned-mismatch unsigned-mismatch.c && ./unsigned-mismatch

#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        if(-1 < 2147488648u) { printf("-1 < 2147488648u is true\n");  }
        else                 { printf("Oops: -1 < 2147488648u is false?\n"); }
}

unsigned-mismatch.c: In function 'main':
unsigned-mismatch.c:5:8: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'int' and 'unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]
    5 |  if(-1 < 2147488648u) { printf("-1 < 2147488648u is true\n");  }
      |        ^
Oops: -1 < 2147488648u is false?
```

In your case you don't have to worry about the compiler warning. First of all you never use the assigned value, so whatever the compiler does to it is irrelevant anyway; secondly, the conversion of an unsigned integer value to a signed integer type which can hold the value is well-defined and works as expected. It is good practice though to eliminate all warnings (and suppress the unavoidable ones with a pragma or compiler option as an indication that you were aware of it and have considered it). In your case you would simply suffix the literal with `ll` to make it a signed `long long int` which easily holds the value. `a` is a `long long int` as well, so it, too, can hold the value, so everything is fine.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> The problem is that in a 32 bit signed integer, using two's complement representation, this bit, the highest-value bit, is used to indicate the sign of the value. If this bit is set the number is negative. In two's complement -1 is "all bits set", and we subtract 1 as usual from there, until we arrive at INT_MIN where all bits are gone except the sign bit.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> In C++ that may be surprising again when overload resolution unexpectedly chooses the funtion taking a `long long` argument even though the literal argument has the *outward appearance* of a plain `int`, lacking any suffix.</sub>

Comment: 2147488648 is not 2^31. It is 2^31+5000.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh. True.